# I can't get PHP zip extension to work on WAMP

Tags: php, zip, wamp, wampserver, php-ziparchive

I am using WAMP with PHP 7.2.4. I need to use PHP's ZipArchive, for which I need the zip.so (php_zip.dll) extension.

I've read it is somehow included in PHP's core since 5.6.x (I believe), so I tried to simply add

```
extension=php.so
```

or

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

to php.ini file (tried both lines, also tried both php.ini and phpForApache.ini). It didn't work, so I've downloaded php_zip.dll file (5.6 NTS x64) from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4/windows , copied it to /wamp64/bin/php7.2.4/ext/ and repeated the process, with the same results.

When I look into PHP error log, this is what I get:

```
[03-Mar-2020 07:15:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/zip.so (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_zip.so.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[03-Mar-2020 07:15:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zip.dll' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_zip.dll (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_php_zip.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I get the first or second line, depending on whether I tried to load php.so, or php_zip.dll extension. Notice the path near the end of those lines: `.../ext/php_php_zip.dll.dll`. Because of this I also tried to load simply `extension=zip`, but no luck.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: your so and dll file is there on ext directory?

Comment: @Tausif only php_zip.dll, I can't find the zip.so file anywhere - I actually thought it wasn't a physical file.